# Le mangio o ne mangio?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Le mangio a 3 a 3 o ne mangio a 3 a 3?

Le mangio 3 per volta o ne mangio 3 per volta?

Le frasi, senza i pronomi “ne/le” sarebbero:

1) mangio le patatine a 3 a 3

2) mangio patatine a 3 a 3

3) mangio le patatine 3 per volta

4) mangio 3 patatine per volta.

Vorrei sapere, se è possibile, quali di queste costruzioni sono corrette/scorrette?

Grazie in anticipo a tutti.

Comment: Secondo me sono tutte corrette.

Comment: Per rispondere, occorre tenere conto del fatto che le frasi con i pronomi seguono altre frasi, a cui i pronomi si riferiscono. È in base alla frase precedente che si può usare il pronome in modo corretto.

Comment: @Benedetta: Tuttavia, Nakamura ha messo nella domanda le frasi con i complimenti diretti che dovrebbero essere sostituiti dai pronomi scritti in modo esplicito.

Comment: Magari è un mio timore inutile: è che non vorrei che si considerassero esempi “in astratto” che poi nella pratica della lingua non si trovano…

Comment: Nakamura: Penso che @Benedetta abbia ragione. Potresti aggiungere alla domanda le frasi che diresti o scriveresti prima di quelle con i pronomi? Se non lo fai, temo non sarà possibile dare risposta alla tua domanda.

Answer (score 1):

Gli esempi fatti sono tutti corretti e si possono trovare nella lingua parlata comune. Spesso la prima preposizione "a" viene omessa, quindi si può anche dire:

"Mangio le patatine tre a tre."

(Nota: di solito è cattivo stile nella lingua scritta usare i simboli numerici per indicare numeri, a meno che non si parli di numeri elevati e molto precisi).

Esempi:

*Perché hai la bocca così gonfia? (*munch*..*munch*) Perché mi piace mangiare le patatine tre a tre!*

oppure:

*... Perché mi piace mangiare le patatine a tre a tre.* (un po' più raro nel parlato)

*... Perché mi piace mangiare (le) patatine (a) tre a tre.*

*... Perché mi piace mangiare tre patatine per volta.*

o anche

*... tre patatine alla volta.*

*... Perché mi piace mangiare (le) patatine tre per/alla volta.*

Il significato è sostanzialmente lo stesso in tutti i casi e tutti i casi sono perfettamente accettabili. Scegliere uno stile rispetto all'altro dipende dalle abitudini del parlante e dal constesto.

Comment: Penso che la domanda fosse sull'uso dei pronomi "le" e "ne" per sostituire "le patatine" e "patatine" in queste frasi.

Comment: @Charo Ah! Hai ragione! Devo aver letto male la domanda. Evidentemente mi sono distratto. Mi sembrava che il dubbio fosse tra quali delle frasi fosse corretta, non sulla sostituzione del sostantivo con "ne".

Comment: @Charo. Non so bene come funziona su questo sito. Dovrei forse cancellare la risposta? Su alcuni siti della catena SE su cui sono attivo se la risposta non è strettamente legata a quanto chiede chi ha fatto la domanda è prassi cancellare la risposta.

Comment: Normalmente è prassi correggere o cancellare una risposta se non ritieni più che sia corretta, ma la decisione spetta a te :).

Comment: A mio parere la risposta di  @LorenzoDonati è coerente con la versione attuale della domanda, che riporta "quali di queste costruzioni sono corrette/scorrette?"